# How to keep Android Wear device connected to WiFi Access Point

Tags: android, wear-os, android-wifi, moto-360

I have an Android Wear device - the **Moto 360 2nd generation** with Android Wear `1.3.0.2230669`. It is connected to a WiFi Access Point. **Bluetooth** is switched **off** and the watch is **not paired**.

Some tests with **Kismet** showed, that the watch is not detected as a client on the Access Point as long as it is in silent mode.
I have a project in which I plan to send notifications to the watch by WiFi (I plan to use the `MQTT` protocol). It is important that the **watch should not be paired** with a smartphone.

How can I accomplish this? Can I install a client on the watch that stays connected to the WiFi AP and is listening to the `MQTT` channel? Or can I configure Android Wear in order to keep a WiFi connection active?

Comment: It really is bad form to keep asking the same question over and over again to try and bump it to the top of the list just because you don't get an answer.

Comment: I still hope that someone knows the answer or even has a hint ... I am pretty desperate.